# Why am i getting Expected corresponding closing tag for JSX fragment

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Not sure why i keep getting this i just cant find the reason dude
Can someone please help me figure out the root of this im clueless
This has had me stumped for like 10 mins

```
return (
    return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>KYC Verification</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className="flex w-full">
        <motion.div
          className="flex justify-center py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 w-full text-black dark:text-neutral-100"
          initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
        >
          <div className="bg-l-fg dark:bg-d-fg w-full max-w-5xl p-3 rounded-lg">
            <h1 className="text-lg text-black dark:text-white font-semibold">KYC Verification</h1>
            <p className="text-black dark:text-neutral-100 mb-3">
              We need to verify your identity to prevent fraud. Please upload a picture of your ID
              (front and back) and a picture of your face.
            </p>
            {!complete && (
              <>
                {showCamera ? (
                  <>
                    <label>Take a picture of your face:</label>
                    <Webcam audio={false} ref={webcamRef} screenshotFormat="image/png" />
                    <button
                      onClick={capture}
                      className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-1 rounded-lg"
                    >
                      Capture
                    </button>
                    <Dropzone onDrop={onDropFace} multiple>
                      {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                        <div {...getRootProps()}>
                          <input {...getInputProps()} />
                          <p
                            className={`${
                              faceImage ? "border-green-500" : "border-indigo-600"
                            } border border-dashed cursor-pointer w-full px-3 py-1 text-center rounded-lg mt-2`}
                          >
                            Don't have a camera? Upload a picture of your face.
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Dropzone>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    {!faceImage && (
                      <>
                        <label>Upload your ID:</label>
                        <Image
                          className="ml-80 mb-3 rounded-2xl"
                          src="/front.png"
                          width={350}
                          height={350}
                        />
                        <Dropzone onDrop={onDropIdFront} multiple>
                          {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                            <div {...getRootProps()}>
                              <input {...getInputProps()} />
                              <p
                                className={`${
                                  idFrontImage ? "border-green-500" : "border-indigo-600"
                                } border border-dashed cursor-pointer w-full px-3 py-1 text-center rounded-lg mt-4`}
                              >
                                Front of ID
                              </p>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </Dropzone>
                        <Dropzone onDrop={onDropIdBack} multiple>
                          {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                            <div {...getRootProps()}>
                              <input {...getInputProps()} />
                              <p
                                className={`${
                                  idBackImage ? "border-green-500" : "border-indigo-600"
                                } border border-dashed cursor-pointer w-full px-3 py-1 text-center rounded-lg mt-4`}
                              >
                                Back of ID
                              </p>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </Dropzone>
                        <button
                          onClick={ Submit}
                          disabled={!idFrontImage || !idBackImage}
                          className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-4 rounded-lg"
                        >
                          Submit
                        </button>
                        <button
                          onClick={toggleCamera}
                          className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-2 rounded-lg"
                        >
                          Use Camera
                        </button>
                      </>
                    )}
                    {faceImage && (
                      <>
                        <label>Upload your ID (back):</label>
                        <Image
                          className="ml-80 mb-3 rounded-2xl"
                          src="/back.png"
                          width={350}
                          height={350}
                        />
                        <Dropzone onDrop={onDropIdBack} multiple>
                          {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                            <div {...getRootProps()}>
                              <input {...getInputProps()} />
                              <p
                                className={`${
                                  idBackImage ? "border-green-500" : "border-indigo-600"
                                } border border-dashed cursor-pointer w-full px-3 py-1 text-center rounded-lg mt-4`}
                              >
                                Back of ID
                              </p>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </Dropzone>
                        <button
                          onClick={handleSubmit}
                          disabled={!idBackImage}
                          className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-4 rounded-lg"
                        >
                          Submit
                        </button>
                        <button
                          onClick={toggleCamera}
                          className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-2 rounded-lg"
                        >
                          Retake Picture
                        </button>
                      </>
                    )}
                  </>
                )}
              </>
            )}

            {faceImage && idFrontImage && idBackImage && (
              <>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={name}
                    placeholder="Enter your name"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <FaRegAddressCard className="inline-block mr-2" />
                  <label htmlFor="name">Address:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={address}
                    placeholder="Enter your address"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <label htmlFor="name">Date of Birth:</label>
                  <input
                    type="date"
                    ref={dob}
                    placeholder="Enter your date of birth"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <label htmlFor="name">Country:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={country}
                    placeholder="Enter your country"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <label htmlFor="name">State:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={state}
                    placeholder="Enter your state"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <FaCity className="inline-block mr-2" />
                  <label htmlFor="name">City:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={city}
                    placeholder="Enter your city"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <label htmlFor="name">Zip Code:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={zip}
                    placeholder="Enter your zip code"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <FaPhone className="inline-block mr-2" />
                  <label htmlFor="name">Phone Number:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={phone}
                    placeholder="Enter your phone number"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <AiOutlineMail className="inline-block mr-2" />
                  <label htmlFor="name">Email:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={email}
                    placeholder="Enter your email"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <label htmlFor="ssn">SSN / SIN / NISS / NIN / OIB:</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    ref={ssn}
                    placeholder="Enter your SSN"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                  />
                </div>
                <button
                  className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-3 rounded-lg"
                  onClick={handleSubmit}
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
                <button
                  className="bg-red-500 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-1 rounded-lg"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setIdFrontImage(null)
                    setIdBackImage(null)
                    setFaceImage(null)
                    setShowCamera(false)
                  }}
                >
                  Retry
                </button>
              </>
            )}

            {fComplete && (
              <>
                {!fIdFrontImage && !fIdFrontImage && (
                  <>
                    <label>Upload your Face + ID:</label>
                    <Image
                      className="ml-80 mb-3 rounded-2xl"
                      src="/front.png"
                      width={350}
                      height={350}
                    />
                    <Dropzone onDrop={onDropFIdFront} multiple>
                      {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                        <div {...getRootProps()}>
                          <input {...getInputProps()} />
                          <p
                            className={`${
                              fIdFrontImage ? "border-green-500" : "border-indigo-600"
                            } border border-dashed cursor-pointer w-full px-3 py-1 text-center rounded-lg mt-4`}
                          >
                            Face + Front of ID
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Dropzone>
                    <Dropzone onDrop={onDropFIdBack} multiple>
                      {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                        <div {...getRootProps()}>
                          <input {...getInputProps()} />
                          <p
                            className={`${
                              fIdBackImage ? "border-green-500" : "border-indigo-600"
                            } border border-dashed cursor-pointer w-full px-3 py-1 text-center rounded-lg mt-4`}
                          >
                            Face + Back of ID
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Dropzone>
                    <Image
                      className="ml-80 mt-4 rounded-2xl"
                      src="/back.png"
                      width={350}
                      height={350}
                    />
                    {fIdFrontImage && fIdBackImage && (
                      <button
                        className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-1 rounded-lg"
                        onClick={fSubmit}
                      >
                        Submit
                      </button>
                    )}
                  </>
                )}
              </>
            )}

            {fIdFrontImage && fIdBackImage (
              <>
              <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center mb-10">
              <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold">Step 4: Upload a proof of address</h2>
              <div className="mt-4">
                <label className="flex items-center">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    className="form-checkbox"
                    checked={billState}
                    onChange={() => setBillState(!billState)}
                  />
                  <span className="ml-2">I do not have a proof of address document</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              {!billState && (
                <div className="mt-4">
                  {bill ? (
                    <div className="relative w-52 h-52">
                      <Image src={bill} alt="Bill Image" layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <div className="w-52 h-52 bg-gray-200 flex justify-center items-center">
                      <FaRegAddressCard className="text-4xl" />
                    </div>
                  )}
                  <Dropzone onDrop={onDropBill}>
                    {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                      <div className="mt-4">
                        <div
                          {...getRootProps()}
                          className="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded cursor-pointer"
                        >
                          <input {...getInputProps()} />
                          Upload Bill
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </Dropzone>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="flex justify-center mb-10">
              <button
                className="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
                onClick={fSubmit}
              >
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
            )
            </div>


          <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
            <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold mb-4">Verification Complete</h1>
            <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-8">
              Thank you for completing the KYC verification process!
            </h2>
            <Image src="/success.png" alt="Success Image" width={300} height={300} />
          </div>
          )}
          </div>
        </motion.div>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've been looking at the ternary operators, the tags, braces, and no matter how thorughly i try i cant for the death of me

Each time i try one of these, just more and more errors occur

Comment: Super clear error, with a super simple solution: use a linter (like eslint or prettier or the like). It'll tell you where things go wrong. And barring that: reduce your code until the problem goes away. You're showing a fairly crazy amount of JSX all in a single return (protip: refactor that to something that composes. No single component should ever be this big), so start removing blocks that _are_ properly closed, starting at the deepest nested elements and then work your way up. Takes maybe a minute or two at most, and finds the problem without anyone's help needed.

Comment: I added one and i get Expected corresponding closing tag for JSX fragment, check edit

Comment: Your edit still has _way_ too much code in it. Give the [mcve] article a read-through, because it's going to help you figure out problems like these _a lot_.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any closing tags for this line
`<div className="bg-l-fg dark:bg-d-fg w-full max-w-5xl p-3 rounded-lg">`
You should add one before
`</motion.div>`

To avoid this kind of problem though, limit the elements you have in one file.

Here's the full jsx

```
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>KYC Verification</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className="flex w-full">
        <motion.div
          className="flex justify-center py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 w-full text-black dark:text-neutral-100"
          initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
        >
          <div className="bg-l-fg dark:bg-d-fg w-full max-w-5xl p-3 rounded-lg">
            <h1 className="text-lg text-black dark:text-white font-semibold">
              KYC Verification
            </h1>
            <p className="text-black dark:text-neutral-100 mb-3">
              We need to verify your identity to prevent fraud. Please upload a
              picture of your ID (front and back) and a picture of your face.
            </p>
            {!complete && (
              <>
                {showCamera ? (
                  <>
                    <label>Take a picture of your face:</label>
                    <Webcam
                      audio={false}
                      ref={webcamRef}
                      screenshotFormat="image/png"
                    />
                    <button
                      onClick={capture}
                      className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-1 rounded-lg"
                    >
                      Capture
                    </button>
                    <Dropzone onDrop={onDropFace} multiple>
                      {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                        <div {...getRootProps()}>
                          <input {...getInputProps()} />
                          <p
                            className={`${
                              faceImage
                                ? 'border-green-500'
                                : 'border-indigo-600'
                            } border border-dashed cursor-pointer w-full px-3 py-1 text-center rounded-lg mt-2`}
                          >
                            Don't have a camera? Upload a picture of your face.
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Dropzone>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    {!faceImage && (
                      <>
                        <label>Upload your ID:</label>
                        <Image
                          className="ml-80 mb-3 rounded-2xl"
                          src="/front.png"
                          width={350}
                          height={350}
                        />
                        <Dropzone onDrop={onDropIdFront} multiple>
                          {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                            <div {...getRootProps()}>
                              <input {...getInputProps()} />
                              <p
                                className={`${
                                  idFrontImage
                                    ? 'border-green-500'
                                    : 'border-indigo-600'
                                } border border-dashed cursor-pointer w-full px-3 py-1 text-center rounded-lg mt-4`}
                              >
                                Front of ID
                              </p>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </Dropzone>
                        <Dropzone onDrop={onDropIdBack} multiple>
                          {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                            <div {...getRootProps()}>
                              <input {...getInputProps()} />
                              <p
                                className={`${
                                  idBackImage
                                    ? 'border-green-500'
                                    : 'border-indigo-600'
                                } border border-dashed cursor-pointer w-full px-3 py-1 text-center rounded-lg mt-4`}
                              >
                                Back of ID
                              </p>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </Dropzone>
                        <button
                          onClick={Submit}
                          disabled={!idFrontImage || !idBackImage}
                          className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-4 rounded-lg"
                        >
                          Submit
                        </button>
                        <button
                          onClick={toggleCamera}
                          className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-2 rounded-lg"
                        >
                          Use Camera
                        </button>
                      </>
                    )}
                    {faceImage && (
                      <>
                        <label>Upload your ID (back):</label>
                        <Image
                          className="ml-80 mb-3 rounded-2xl"
                          src="/back.png"
                          width={350}
                          height={350}
                        />
                        <Dropzone onDrop={onDropIdBack} multiple>
                          {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                            <div {...getRootProps()}>
                              <input {...getInputProps()} />
                              <p
                                className={`${
                                  idBackImage
                                    ? 'border-green-500'
                                    : 'border-indigo-600'
                                } border border-dashed cursor-pointer w-full px-3 py-1 text-center rounded-lg mt-4`}
                              >
                                Back of ID
                              </p>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </Dropzone>
                        <button
                          onClick={handleSubmit}
                          disabled={!idBackImage}
                          className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-4 rounded-lg"
                        >
                          Submit
                        </button>
                        <button
                          onClick={toggleCamera}
                          className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-2 rounded-lg"
                        >
                          Retake Picture
                        </button>
                      </>
                    )}
                  </>
                )}
              </>
            )}

            {faceImage && idFrontImage && idBackImage && (
              <>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={name}
                    placeholder="Enter your name"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <FaRegAddressCard className="inline-block mr-2" />
                  <label htmlFor="name">Address:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={address}
                    placeholder="Enter your address"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <label htmlFor="name">Date of Birth:</label>
                  <input
                    type="date"
                    ref={dob}
                    placeholder="Enter your date of birth"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <label htmlFor="name">Country:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={country}
                    placeholder="Enter your country"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <label htmlFor="name">State:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={state}
                    placeholder="Enter your state"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <FaCity className="inline-block mr-2" />
                  <label htmlFor="name">City:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={city}
                    placeholder="Enter your city"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <label htmlFor="name">Zip Code:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={zip}
                    placeholder="Enter your zip code"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <FaPhone className="inline-block mr-2" />
                  <label htmlFor="name">Phone Number:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={phone}
                    placeholder="Enter your phone number"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <AiOutlineMail className="inline-block mr-2" />
                  <label htmlFor="name">Email:</label>
                  <input
                    ref={email}
                    placeholder="Enter your email"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <label htmlFor="ssn">SSN / SIN / NISS / NIN / OIB:</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    ref={ssn}
                    placeholder="Enter your SSN"
                    className="w-full bg-l-fg h-[2.85rem]  rounded-r-md dark:bg-d-bg text-black dark:text-white font-neue font-bold tracking-wide focus:outline-none px-3 border border-gray-400 dark:border-neutral-800"
                  />
                </div>
                <button
                  className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-3 rounded-lg"
                  onClick={handleSubmit}
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
                <button
                  className="bg-red-500 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-1 rounded-lg"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setIdFrontImage(null);
                    setIdBackImage(null);
                    setFaceImage(null);
                    setShowCamera(false);
                  }}
                >
                  Retry
                </button>
              </>
            )}

            {fComplete && (
              <>
                {!fIdFrontImage && !fIdFrontImage && (
                  <>
                    <label>Upload your Face + ID:</label>
                    <Image
                      className="ml-80 mb-3 rounded-2xl"
                      src="/front.png"
                      width={350}
                      height={350}
                    />
                    <Dropzone onDrop={onDropFIdFront} multiple>
                      {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                        <div {...getRootProps()}>
                          <input {...getInputProps()} />
                          <p
                            className={`${
                              fIdFrontImage
                                ? 'border-green-500'
                                : 'border-indigo-600'
                            } border border-dashed cursor-pointer w-full px-3 py-1 text-center rounded-lg mt-4`}
                          >
                            Face + Front of ID
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Dropzone>
                    <Dropzone onDrop={onDropFIdBack} multiple>
                      {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                        <div {...getRootProps()}>
                          <input {...getInputProps()} />
                          <p
                            className={`${
                              fIdBackImage
                                ? 'border-green-500'
                                : 'border-indigo-600'
                            } border border-dashed cursor-pointer w-full px-3 py-1 text-center rounded-lg mt-4`}
                          >
                            Face + Back of ID
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Dropzone>
                    <Image
                      className="ml-80 mt-4 rounded-2xl"
                      src="/back.png"
                      width={350}
                      height={350}
                    />
                    {fIdFrontImage && fIdBackImage && (
                      <button
                        className="bg-indigo-600 w-full py-1 px-3 mt-1 rounded-lg"
                        onClick={fSubmit}
                      >
                        Submit
                      </button>
                    )}
                  </>
                )}
              </>
            )}

            {fIdFrontImage &&
              fIdBackImage(
                <>
                  <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center mb-10">
                    <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold">
                      Step 4: Upload a proof of address
                    </h2>
                    <div className="mt-4">
                      <label className="flex items-center">
                        <input
                          type="checkbox"
                          className="form-checkbox"
                          checked={billState}
                          onChange={() => setBillState(!billState)}
                        />
                        <span className="ml-2">
                          I do not have a proof of address document
                        </span>
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    {!billState && (
                      <div className="mt-4">
                        {bill ? (
                          <div className="relative w-52 h-52">
                            <Image
                              src={bill}
                              alt="Bill Image"
                              layout="fill"
                              objectFit="cover"
                            />
                          </div>
                        ) : (
                          <div className="w-52 h-52 bg-gray-200 flex justify-center items-center">
                            <FaRegAddressCard className="text-4xl" />
                          </div>
                        )}
                        <Dropzone onDrop={onDropBill}>
                          {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                            <div className="mt-4">
                              <div
                                {...getRootProps()}
                                className="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded cursor-pointer"
                              >
                                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                                Upload Bill
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </Dropzone>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <div className="flex justify-center mb-10">
                    <button
                      className="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
                      onClick={fSubmit}
                    >
                      Submit
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </>
              )}

            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
              <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold mb-4">Verification Complete</h1>
              <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-8">
                Thank you for completing the KYC verification process!
              </h2>
              <Image
                src="/success.png"
                alt="Success Image"
                width={300}
                height={300}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </motion.div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I added one and i get Expected corresponding closing tag for JSX fragment, check edit

Comment: I've added the full jsx, so you can see.